# How to read .xslt file which is not in classpath

Tags: java, xslt, classloader, inputstream

I want to change the code bellow to read (*.xslt file) from  **serverPath** which point to the location who is not inside in a classpath.

`XSLProcessor processor = new XSLProcessor();
ClassLoader cLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream xslStream = cLoader.getResourceAsStream("serverPath");
XSLStylesheet style = processor.newXSLStylesheet(xslStream);`

When I change the .xslt location outside of classpath I get `xsltStream null pointer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a native file path just you can simply use a normal `FileInputStream`.